# Is there any way to NOT ignore .git in subfolders?

Tags: git, monorepo

I've got a project sort of like this:

```
+ MonoRepo
  - .git
  + PublicUtil
    - .git
    - PublicFile.js
  + PrivateStuff
    - internalUseOfPublicUtil.js
```

With this structure we can have updates pushed to PublicUtil that are version controlled and viewable to the public.  Then, at the same time from the development side, we just use MonoRepo for all commits, and then have a script that will push to subgits if necessary.

We need this because (in reality), the project is much bigger.  Imagine 30 PublicUtil repos.  We can not use submodules because that would lead to in-house devs having to push to multiple repos for one update (often, multiple repos need modification at the same time), followed by an update to MonoRepo.  This means lots and lots of wasted time connecting the dots between different PRs, and occasional breakages when one submodule gets pulled without the other, or something hasn't been pushed yet, etc.

Anyways, now that I've explained why I'm trying to achieve this strange thing, here's the issue/question:

As far as I can tell, git does not allow users to push a .git from a subfolder.  But, I might be wrong.  So, I might as well ask:

**Is there any way at all to *not* ignore .git in subfolders?**

I'm able to set the project up just fine, but if I push MonoRepo and then pull it on another computer, it won't come with any of the subfolder gits, and I wont be able to do any of this fancy public releasing sections of a private git stuff.

P.S. Currently, my best guess on how to approach this is to make a pre-commit & post-commit hook for renaming git folders, only used by MonoRepo.  I'd also need a post-clone one too... it would work, but I'd rather not be so heavy handed if possible.

Comment: Just run `rm -rf` on each `.git` that is not the top level `.git`. You'll get the same result when you now add all the work-tree files that you would have, if you hadn't removed the `.git` directories but *did* somehow defeat the submodule-detector. (Which, yes, you can do, but this way is easier.)

Comment: I'm trying to include these .gits (and their content) in my parent .git.  Not remove them.  Did I misunderstand your advice?

Comment: You don't get a choice. Git doesn't store repositories. Git only stores *files* (as entries within individual commits). There's a special type of file, called a *gitlink*, that stores the hash ID of a commit in another Git repository. This is only useful as part of a submodule: the submodule tells your Git what other Git repository to clone. Then the gitlink tells your Git what other commit in that other GIt repository to `git checkout` in that other Git repository.

Comment: I have no git submodules.  I've gotten around those.  And I'm only trying to store files.  In particular, the files found in `**/.git`.

Comment: Well, you could store them, but then you'd have to turn them into a Git repository to check them out—because the files stored in the commits in the Git repository are not stored as regular files, but rather as a database of objects. You then have to run `git checkout` to extract the Git-ized files from the database into a useful format.

Comment: Because Git won't write anything named `.git`, you'd have to rename the `.git` directories to some other name, and then use a post-monorepo-checkout to re-rename them back to `.git`. Then you'd have to `cd` into each one and run `git checkout` on some commit ... but that's what a submodule does; it just does it with that somewhat annoying syntax and use of gitlink entries to control which commit gets checked out. (But you'd need that anyway, in order to remember which commit to check out—it's no good checking out the latest `master` when that doesn't work with the older superproject.)

Comment: So far, the renaming route seems the most accessible.  I'm aware that normally git wont write anything named .git, but I was hoping there was an exception to this.

The way I have it right now I do not need to `cd into each one and run git checkout`.  That's kind of the point.  When I pull a commit to mono, I want it to be exactly what was pushed, no linking to mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out a solution which works for projects that have node.js around.  If I was better at bash, I would have made this a bash script.  If you can do this in bash, I'll consider it a true answer to the question.  Anyways, here's my setup script:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function createRenamer(forCommit) {
  const from = forCommit ? ".xgit" : ".git";
  const to = forCommit ? ".git" : ".xgit";
  return [
    `for x in $(find */ -name ${from}); do`,
    `  mv ${forCommit ? "-n" : ""} $x $(echo "$x" | sed 's/${from.replace(".", "\\.")}$/${to}/')`,
    `done`,
    forCommit ? `&& git add */.xgit` : ""
  ].join("\n");
}

const hooksPath = path.join(__dirname, "./.git/hooks");

const preCommitFilename = hooksPath + "/pre-commit";
fs.writeFileSync(preCommitFilename, createRenamer(true));
fs.chmodSync(preCommitFilename, 0o755); 

const postCommitFilename = hooksPath + "/post-commit";
fs.writeFileSync(postCommitFilename, createRenamer(false));
fs.chmodSync(postCommitFilename, 0o755); 

exec(postCommitFilename);
```

It has to be run once, at any point, and it'll init all the sub repos.  What it does is:

- Creates a pre-clone bash script which

  - updates every `**/.git` to a `**/.xgit`
  - then git adds all `.xgit` files.  This really only needs to be done once, but it makes new sub repos more automatic
- Then it creates a post-clone bash script which updates every `**/.xgit` back to a `**/.git` so it can be useful again
- Then it runs the post-clone, to initialize the sub repos

**CAVEAT**: This is still an incomplete solution.  If someone pulls the repo, the .gits will not be updated until the rename script is run.  Further, the way `mv` works is mind numbingly stupid, and there is seemingly no way to rename a directory without inadvertently copying into the folder you want to name it to.  This blows my mind, and surely I must be wrong... ([How can I rename a directory in bash, without overwriting or moving inside a pre-existing target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088040/how-can-i-rename-a-directory-in-bash-without-overwriting-or-moving-inside-a-pre))

I'll update this when I have the kinks figured out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of removing the .git subfolders, in order to commit in a true monorepo, you can, at any time, record a subfolder (like PublicUtil) in its own Git repository.

All you need to have is its .git stored elsewhere, *outside* the main monorepo structure, and do a

```
 git --git-dir=/path/to/monorepo§publicUtils \
     --work-tree=/path/to/PublicUtils/.git add .

 git --git-dir=/path/to/monorepo§publicUtils \
     --work-tree=/path/to/PublicUtils/.git commit -m "record PublicUtils"
```

That allows you to maintain two sets of history:

- one global in your monorepo
- one specific to a subfolder project.

All that could be automated through hooks which would detect which subfolders (projects) are involved with a new commits, and make the additional `git --git-dir=... --work-tree=...` calls.

Comment: If I pulled the MonoRepo, it would not contain the subfolder .gits.  They would still not be included in monorepo.  Or did I misunderstand what you're saying?

Comment: @SephReed Yes, that is the idea: separate the monorepo from its multi project repos (which could be part of a separate repository with submodules). I would recommand keeping the multiple repositories in a centralized place, to be updated automatically only when anyone pushed back to the main monorepo.