# How can I rename a directory in bash, without overwriting or moving inside a pre-existing target?

Tags: bash, directory, rename

I want to rename a directory, only if the target does not exist.

To do this the syntax should be

`mv -n -T my/dir my/dirNew`

Where -n means "don't overwrite" and -T means "don't move into the target"

(https://askubuntu.com/a/763915/461996)

Unfortunately, `-T` is not an option on OSX, so any scripts making use of it won't work for OSX.

**So, how can I rename a directory only if it won't overwrite one?**

I've checked, and `rename` is not a standard I can depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not necessary for you to achieve the same with `mv` command completely, you can simply do it like :

```
[ ! -d "$destination_dir_name" ] && mv -n "$current_dir_name" "$destination_dir_name"
```

`[ ! -d "$destination_dir_name" ]` would only evaluate to true if there is no such directory. If this evaluates to true `&&` would confirm execution of `mv "$current_dir_name" "$destination_dir_name`".

Comment: I would use `[ -e ...` (because there might be something other than a directory there), and also wrap all variable references in double-quotes (to avoid parsing problems if the paths contain any funny characters).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thats right, I wrapped it in double quotes. `-e` also right, but better i just placed a `-n` in `mv` command.